# C-Style 2D Array as ivar

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

In C, we could do the following to create a 2D array:

```
int intArray[10][10];
```

In C99, we could create a VLA:

```
size_t col = 10;
size_t row = 10;

int array[row][col];
```

Within a method in Objective-C, I can create a 2D array that hold `id`s as follows:

```
id genObjectArray[10][10];
```

Is it possible to create an 2d array ivar in Objective-C?

The following is what I have tried:

```
@interface myClass ()
{
    id objArray[][]; 
    //This doesn't work, unless I specific size.
    //I want to do this, so that I could specific the size later during 
    //runtime
}
```

In C, I could do the following and allocate space for a 2D array later within a block scope:

```
int **array;
int *elements;
```

I can do the same within Objective-C, too, but the problem arises when I use `id` or other object types; other words, the following is not valid:

```
id **array;
id *elements;
```

Thus, my question is, is it possible to declare a C-style 2D array as ivar that holds `id`s?

I understand that we could achieve that using normal `NS(Mutable)Array`; but this just serves for educational purposes.

Comment: Hi Unheilig. It's not about your question. I have frequently seen you reveiwing. It occured to me that how can you *sweep* questions when they seem so scarce? I mean that most of the time the reviewing box is empty (for example in *Late Answers*) but you can manage to fulfill your 20 review limit. Would you nicely tell me if there is any trick in it? Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @Ormoz Hi, with the help of my Review Queue Magic 8 ball a priori? “Which queue will need to be reviewed besides Close Votes?”
No, joking :-) My reviews compared to those by other reviewers amount to only a small fraction. Just thought I would help during breaks from reading books. Really, there is no trick. It is pure coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Anyway, you are my heroine

Comment: Congratulations for making TOP on Late Answer Review. Do Maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  For a C99 VLA, the space required for the array is allocated at the point the array is declared.  For an ivar, the analogous time to do that would be when the object was allocated and initialized, but there's no support in Objective C to do that.  You'd need to have a stronger definition of what an object constructor can do (more like Java's constructors than Objective C's initializers).

The closest you can get would be something like this:

```
@interface myClass () {
    id * objArray;
}

-(instancetype)initWithRow:(size_t)row col:(size_t)col {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        objArray = calloc(row * col * sizeof(id));
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    free(objArray);
}
```

In that case, you're declaring the ivar as a pointer and managing the storage yourself (and the stride, for a multi-dimensional array).

Obviously, `NSArray` is better in all possible ways.

Comment: `id *objArray` would not work here, however, due to lack of explicit ownership. Thanks.